# get multiple selection in jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, listbox

I've got a noob question.

I am trying to make a multi-selection listbox in HTML. If the user's selections contains the item "OTHER", a textbox will appear below the listbox.

I first came up with this:

```
onchange = "displayDiv(this.options[this.selectedIndex].text)
--------------------------------------------------------------
function displayDiv(val) {
    if (val == "OTHER") {
        $("#divName").show();
    } else {
        $("#divName").hide();
    }
}
```

then I realized this won't work with multiple selection. How do you retrieve all the selected items as an array or list in jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a `<select>` element, the returned value of `$('select').val()` is an `Array` with the selected values.

You can use

```
$('select').val().indexOf('OTHER') > -1
```

> In jQuery < 3.0, if there is no selection at all, the `val()` will return null, so you should check if the value != null before use the indexOf:

```
if ($('select').val()) {
    if ($('select').val().indexOf('OTHER') > -1) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Dekel! This is partially working. I found that .val() returns the value of option not the string. But since now I know that value of the option i can work it around that. Thanks again!

Comment: As mentioned in my answer - if the `select` element is a multiple-select, the value returned by `val()` is an `Array`, and not a string. You are welcome to accept my answer if it helped you.

Comment: Yeah you were definitely right. It's just the setup of my project is like this '<option> selected="selected' value="5">OTHER</option>' So it returns 5 instead of "OTHER". What attribute should i use to get the string but not the value?

Comment: Yes, if you have different value than the text of the option you should use the value. the `val()` function gets you the values :)